# Open modal bootstrap after filtering data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Story:

User enter data in a search field to find a client, it filters with ajax and lists in a table the results, 
If there is no results or phone number was not found. And number has more / or 7 digits: I open a modal, it works, but after it loads, if I type one  or two more digits, it validates again, and is passing to the condition but the modal is not opening.I need to open it from php,the code I am using after the search is:

```
 <?php

     $isPhone = $this->isPhone;
     $strPhone = $this->strPhone;
     $strPhoneCount = strlen($strPhone);

     if(!$isPhone && $strPhoneCount >= 7 ){

        echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">';
        echo '$(document).ready(function(){';
        echo '$( "#dialog" ).modal("show");';
        echo '});';
        echo '</script>';

     }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because document ready event is triggered already. Just remove it from your code:

```
 if(!$isTel && $strTelCount >= 7 ){

    echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">';
    echo '$( "#dialog" ).modal("show");';
    echo '</script>';

 }
```

Comment: I remove it. but has the same effect. Just open once. I am using it inside a view of Zend Framework.

Comment: @RPR do you have a page example?

Comment: unfortunately I just have it locally

Comment: @RPR can you show how you call it using JS? Why not open it using success handler?

Comment: You could use .on() . Which responds to the event of your choosing rather than the .ready().